# Can't make urlChanged signal work

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I'm writing an application with QWebView class and I want to catch when it redirectes to the other url address using urlChanged(const QUrl&) signal, but at run time I get this

> Object::connect: No such signal QWebView::urlChanged(url)

here is my code

```
   #include <QString>
   #include "test.h"
   #include <QUrl>
   #include <QWebView>
   #include <stdio.h>
   QFapp::QFapp(QWidget* parent):QWidget(parent)
   {
      QWebView*view = new QWebView;
      QUrl url("http://google.com");
      view->load(url);
      view->show();
      connect(view,SIGNAL(urlChanged(url)),this,SLOT(GetToken()));
   }
  void QFapp::GetToken()
  {
     printf("Signal is emited");
  }
```

and this is the header file

```
   #include <QWidget>
   #include <QString>
   #include <QUrl>
   #include <QWebView>
   class QFapp: public QWidget
   {
      Q_OBJECT
    public:
        QFapp(QWidget* parent = 0);
    public slots:
      void GetToken();
    private:
      QWebView* view;
        QUrl url;
     };
```

and there are no compile time warnings.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. This is my first experience with Qt (not a school assignment ) so any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
 connect(view,SIGNAL(urlChanged(url)),this,SLOT(GetToken()));
```

the SIGNAL macro takes in a function *signature*, and is not a function call. It should look like this:

```
connect(view,SIGNAL(urlChanged(QUrl)),this,SLOT(GetToken()));
```

This signal will emit whenever the url of the WebView changes, and pass you the url that it changed to.